# What determines how often my drivatar appears in races?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

I've been increasing my drivatar sync %, but I'm not noticing the number of races my drivatar performs correlating to that very well.  What can I do to get him into more races?

Comment: I think it uses people on your friends list who play Forza, and then picks random players from Xbox Live to fill out the slots. I'm not positive not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When racing in career mode, it will always pull from friends list first. If you dont have 15 friends that play forza 5 it will fill it gaps with random Drivatars, but these will be the same drivatars throughout the entire league's set of races.

When doing free mode the drivatars always randomize, and your friends may not appear. So if you want your drivatar to appear more, get more friends into the game. their career will have your drivatar.